# Trouble sending form data to PHP page

Tags: javascript, php

I currently have a form set up inside a PHP echo. Traditionally my forms have a submit button to send data to a separate PHP document to add to or alter my database, but this time I have  tags inside of a `<select>` tag, and I'm using javascript to automatically submit the form when one of the option tags is selected with `onchange="this.form.submit()".` In my PHP document, I am using `if (isset($_POST['completeStatus']) {PHP CODE};` to see if one of the options was selected inside the form, but for some reason it isn't working for me. It seems that the `isset` function only knows when a button is clicked, not an option tag. Please correct me if I'm wrong. I'm not sure if there is a different solution to make this work correctly, or if there is something wrong in my code that I'm not seeing.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<center><div class='taskWrapper'><div class='taskTitles'><p class='subjectTitle'>subject</p><p class='taskSubject'>" . $row['subject'] ."</p></div>". " " .
                     "<div class='taskTitles'><p class='messageTitle'>Message</p><p class='taskMessage'>". $row['message'] ."</p></div>". " " .
                     "<div class='taskTitles'><form action='includes/changestatus.inc.php' method='POST'>
                       <p class='statusTitle'>Status</p><select class='taskStatus' name='myselect' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
                                                             <option value=". $row['calenderid'] .">".$row['mystatus']."</option>
                                                             <option name='stuckStatus' value=". $row['calenderid'] .">Two</option>
                                                             <option name='progressStatus' value=". $row['calenderid'] .">Three</option>
                                                             <option name='completeStatus' value=". $row['calenderid'] .">Four</option>
                                                             <input name='statusDate' type='hidden' value=". $urlDate ."></input>
                                                             <input name='statusMonth' type='hidden' value=". $urlMonth ."></input>
                                                             <input name='statusTZ' type='hidden' value=". $urlTZ ."></input>
                                                         </select>
                     </form></div></center>" ." ";
}
```

Here's the PHP doc the form submits to

```
require 'dbh.inc.php';


    if (isset($_POST['completeStatus'])) {echo "working";}
```

For testing purposes I'm expecting it to navigate and stay on the PHP page when option 4 is clicked on my form  and echo out "working", but the block of code isn't being run. It's being sent to the correct PHP doc but the if statement won't run.

Comment: You've got `<input ...>` inside your `<select> ..... </select>`, that looks weird. I know they are hidden, but I still wouldn't do that.

Comment: Any reason not to? I could put them outside of the <select> tags and but I don't see any difference.  @KIKO Software

Comment: Just put your HTML code through the [Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org), or use the one build into your browser, and see if anything comes up. If it doesn't, then I was wrong to be worried about that. I think it will also complain about the `</input>` tags.

Comment: You're creating inputs with the same name in a loop. When you submit the form, the value of `$_POST['completeStatus']` will come from just one of the inputs with that name (I think it will be the last one).

Comment: There are also missing single quotes around the values you fill from `$row`, that might work, or not. For instance a number will work, but a date like this `2019/4/2` might not.

Comment: The names of options don't become POST parameters, only the names of inputs.

Comment: So you should be using `$_POST['myselect']`, not `$_POST['completeStatus']`.

Comment: The `.` at the end of the `echo` statement should be `;`. I assume that's a copying error.

Comment: Why do all your options have the same value?

Comment: I need to have a different values on each of the <option> tags so I can update my database accordingly. If I use '$_POST['myselect']', I cant do that

Comment: All my option tags have the same value so I know which row to update in my database

Comment: I didn't see that you were creating a different form each time through the loop, I thought these were all rows in one big form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names of options don't become POST parameters. You should be using the name of the `<select>`, `$_POST['myselect']`.

Then you need to give all the options different values, so you can tell which option was chosen. The value of `$_POST['myselect']` will be one of those values.

I'm not sure what the first `<option>` is for. I suspect what you really want to do is select the current value by default, I've added code for that with `($row['mystatus'] == 'stuckStatus' ? 'selected' : '')`.

I added another hidden input with the ID of the task. `$_POST['calendarId']` will contain `$row['calendarid']` for the form that the user submitted.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<center><div class='taskWrapper'><div class='taskTitles'><p class='subjectTitle'>subject</p><p class='taskSubject'>" . $row['subject'] ."</p></div>". " " .
                 "<div class='taskTitles'><p class='messageTitle'>Message</p><p class='taskMessage'>". $row['message'] ."</p></div>". " " .
                 "<div class='taskTitles'><form action='includes/changestatus.inc.php' method='POST'>
                   <p class='statusTitle'>Status</p><select class='taskStatus' name='myselect' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
                                                         <option value='stuckStatus' " . ($row['mystatus'] == 'stuckStatus' ? 'selected' : '') . ">Two</option>
                                                         <option value='progressStatus' " . ($row['mystatus'] == 'progressStatus' ? 'selected' : '') . ">Three</option>
                                                         <option value='completeStatus' " . ($row['mystatus'] == 'completeStatus' ? 'selected' : '') . ">Four</option>
                                                     </select>
                   <input name="calendarId' type='hidden' value='" . $row['calenderid'] . "'>
                   <input name='statusDate' type='hidden' value=". $urlDate ."></input>
                   <input name='statusMonth' type='hidden' value=". $urlMonth ."></input>
                   <input name='statusTZ' type='hidden' value=". $urlTZ ."></input>
                 </form></div></center>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. How can I get the value of the '<option>' tags and set it to a variable in my PHP doc?

Comment: It's in `$_POST['myselect']`, like I said in the answer.